# Asking for DSL Router password instead of showing my site when trying to connect to apache server?

Tags: apache, networking, router

I'm trying to access an apache server hosted on my PC typing it's IP on my 3G notebook, but the browser is asking for the DSL Router password instead of showing my site. Weirdly, my friends can access my site from their computers. I have already accessed the router (a comtrend) and added port 80 to "NAT -- Virtual Servers Setup".

Answer (score 0):

'Sounds like you're typing in the IP address of your router instead of your PC.

Look at "ipconfig" in a command prompt (I'm guessing you're probably on Windows: otherwise type "ifconfig") to get your host's actual IP address.

Or take your notebook off your LAN (e.g. take it to a Starbuck's or something) and access your PC from an external network (like your friends are doing).